# devise reconfirmable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I would like to use the devise option :reconfirmable in my user model, so whenever a user changes his email, he needs to confirm it with a link sent by email.

The big problem is, that the email gets never sent ...

My setup is with devise 2.1.2 is:

user model:

```
attr_accessible: unconfirmed_email, ...

devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable, :omniauthable
```

in the initilizer devise.rb:

```
config.reconfirmable = true
```

in the routes:

```
devise_for :users
```

in the form the model field unconfirmed_email gets set properly. I checked this through the console.

The first confirmation email, when a user registers on the page gets send out without problem.

I tried debugging the problem with adding this code to the initializers directory to overwrite the devise methode that gets triggered as a after_update hook:

```
module Devise::Models::Confirmable
  def send_confirmation_instructions
    debugger
  end
end
```

it seems like send_confirmation_instructions is never called, since I never get to the debugger.

Do I somehow need to call reconfirmable, or does it gets triggered automatically when setting the model attribute "unconfirmed_email" to a new email address?

Thankfull for any help, 
j.

Comment: For reconfirmable to work you have to add a new column to your User table
't.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable'
Have you already done this ?

Comment: hi janders. thats all set up, I have the attribute in my user model and in attr_accessible ... I still havent solved this problem, so any help is very wellcome.

Comment: I am sorry, can't figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 46, accepted):

OK, this is embarrassing..

After diving into the Devise code, I figured out that you don't need to set the `unconfirmed_email` attribute of your user model, but just change the existing email attribute. The attribute `unconfirmed_email` is just used internally for Devise to store the email address until it's confirmed.

Later version of devise gem explains this in initial migration. Here is "Confirmable" section (note the comment on the last line) from `XXX_devise_create_users.rb` migration:

```
  ## Confirmable
  t.string   :confirmation_token
  t.datetime :confirmed_at
  t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
  t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
```

Sorry for bothering, but hopefully this can help somebody having the same problem...

Comment: Thanks for this. Good to know that Devise "automagically" populates `unconfirmed_email` when I update `email` in the model. Don't forget to mark your answer as "Accepted" (yes, even though you answered it yourself!).

Comment: Yes... You thought right.. even if it was after 2 years.. it was helpfull to me. :)