# Does devise set unconfirmed_mail only when changing the email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

So this is my first question on stackoverflow. I hope it contains all information needed.

As I successfully implemented a confirmation routine with devise I was able to see that after a new User registered with the Devise::RegistrationController it does not set the `unconfirmed_email` field of the resource.

A issue (which I can't find right now) said something about changing the `email` will set the `unconfirmed_email` field.

Is that true or am I doing something wrong while register a User the first time?

Comment: This one might help you to setup the confirmable.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387172/devise-reconfirmable
 and 
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable

Comment: Thank you! That acutally explains everything. It will get set when changing a User's email, not  while register a User.